# Python call inner function inside another function

Tags: python, scope, nested-function

Edited!
I wanted to reference inner function return value outside of outer function, and actually inside of another function.

Example:

```
def m1():
    def m2():
        x= 'A'
        y= 'B'
        pre_solution = x+y
        return pre_solution
    pre_solution = m2()
    m1_solution = pre_solution*2
    return m1_solution

print(m1())
```

Now I want to create a new function and I need the return value of m2() to be in it:

```
def m3():
    pre_solution = m2()
    m3_solution = pre_solution*3
    return m3_solution

print(m3())
```

I get an error that m2 is not defined. I need to get pre_solution value without using copy and paste(since the real code has many more lines in it). Here is my current work around but I wanted to see if there was an easier way.

```
def m3():
    x= 'A'
    y= 'B'
    pre_solution = x+y
    m3_solution = pre_solution*3
    return m3_solution

print(m3())
```

I'm doing it for an assignment that uses autograder and only evaluates code inside of the functions, not the global scope, m1() and m3() are going to be evaluated but if I put m2() into global scope it won't be. Hope it makes sense. It's my very first question on here.

Thank you

Comment: If you put `m2()` function outside `m1()`, `m3()` will recognize it. Do you really need to nest `m2()`?

Comment: it is not possible to write code "without any global variables" since **your functions are defined globally**, I don't see how defining one extra function in the global scope makes it invalid for your assignment.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen its probably a restriction from someone who doesn't understand that functions are values and function names are variables. They mean "no global ints, strings etc"

Comment: Basically I'm trying to avoid doing copy and paste to recreate all the steps I did in m2() to get the return value which I need to use in another function. I don't really need a nested function in m1() but was hoping to use m2() return value for later functions and don't know how to reference it. The current work around for me is just to copy and paste. I'm going it for an assignment that's using an autograder and does not recognize anything within a global scope(it's looking to evaluate the functions).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want somthing like this :

```
def m1():
    def m2():
        m2.var = "Cat" * 2
        return m2.var
    m1.x = m2()
    return m1.x + 'Dog'

m1()

def m3():
    y = m1.x
    z = y * 2
    return z

print(m3())
```

This method helps you to get the variable inside outer functions.